# How can I use a class to display specific element after display: none?

Tags: html, css, class, outlook, styles

I am creating an email with different variable fields, these are to be pushed through by the email client and will then update the name of a class.

Originally I had this set up like:

```
.%%payment_frequency%%
{
    display: none;
```

which would update to either Installment or Annual, this then is applied to the various HTML elements that should not be shown. This works well for some email clients but not Outlook, I have discovered it doesn't work in Outlook due to some elements having multiple classes on due to 3 different variable options with 3 separate classes.

Question is, can I do this in reverse and have a 'display: none' style applied to the element and then use a class to show that particular element when needed? I have tried but not been able to figure this out, so any advice would help.

Comment: You can use the `!important` rule to override inline styles: https://css-tricks.com/override-inline-styles-with-css/.  I would say though you should try to avoid using this (unless it's a one off email template) as it can lead to maintenance nightmares or styling issues in the future

Comment: I'm not sure what you are using to preprocess your e-mail, but instead of hiding elements that you don't want to show, why don't you simply _not_ include the elements you don't want to show. That way you don't have to mess around with double classes.

Comment: @Milanzor We're using Silverpop to send the emails but with the implementation we are having to use their Transact product which doesn't allow dynamic content. We have 24 different versions of the same template which include small changes so would be using the same template and using the variable feeds to show the specific element we need for that email. It's easier than managing 24 emails where it's just one table row which is different.

Comment: @Sam You would have to use CSS specificities to overrule your display: none class. First I'll say that there are probably e-mail clients out there that will not interpet your CSS properly (some even strip it out), Outlook is known to have very bad HTML+CSS e-mail rendering, so be careful there. I'll clarify in an answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use a more specific CSS class to show the element again.
Your provided code:

```
.%%payment_frequency%%
{
    display: none;
}
```

Will compile to, for example:

```
.Annual{
    display: none;
}
```

So in order to have certain '.Annual' rows show instead of hide, make a more specific CSS class to actually show it.

I imagine you have a table like this:

```
<table>
    <tr class="Annual">
        <td>Some stuff</td>
        <td>Some more stuff</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Annual ForceShowAnnual">
        <td>Some stuff</td>
        <td>Some more stuff</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I've added the ForceShowAnnual class so we can do the following:

```
.Annual{
    display: none;
}

.Annual.ForceShowAnnual{
    display: block;
}
```

This means the .Annual.ForceShowAnnual is a more specific CSS selector opposed to the .Annual selector, making it overrule the display: none;

This solution does need you to add the extra "ForceShowAnnual" class to rows you want to show.

Comment: The problem I've found is Outlook will only recognise one class per element so I wouldn't be able to use both 'Annual' and 'ForceShowAnnual' in the same <tr>. If I could then my original method would have worked but unfortunately I'm limited to one class.

Comment: I was expecting Outlook to give problems, because when doesn't it! If you cannot use this solution, you will have to try getting an inline 'style="display: none;"' on it. It's that or contact the developers that made the software/CMS to provide a way of doing what you want.

Comment: I am having to go down the inline option, I'm trying to work around the variables now to have it hide when needed (or show with them all hidden already). If Outlook wasn't going to cause issues enough, Gmail has caused even greater as it strips out the header and footers completely so I can't use any classes there! Thanks for your help on this

Comment: Yep, Gmail also has way of its own, stripping out 'security risks'. Your best bed is to preprocess your e-mail through Mailchimps 'Beaker' (I think thats what they used to call it), http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/ or Foundation 'Inliner', http://foundation.zurb.com/emails/inliner-v2.html so all CSS is moved to inline style attributes, giving you the best possible rendering in all e-mail clients. But I understand this can be a challenge in your current setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two classes

```
.show{
  display:block;
}
```

and other class

```
.hide{
display:none;
}
```

or you can play with css visibility property

```
.visible{
visibility: visible;
}
.non-visible{
visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: In total I have 11 elements that need to change at different points and have got these to 3 main subjects that they share. I can put a variable field of the 3 subjects which would have allowed it to hide the others, just need to use it the opposite way round